# Interpretation of survplot output summary and the figure

Tags: survival

I have 4 categories for cytogenetic risk to find the survival I ran this

```
TMB_NONSYNONYMOUS = survfit(Surv(OS_MONTHS, Status)~ RISK_CYTO, data = Final_cox_146)
```

Where RISK_CYTO is Good, Intermediate, Poor and N.D

The output figure is this
[image: survfit output]

When I check the survfit object I see this

```
TMB_NONSYNONYMOUS
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(OS_MONTHS, Status) ~ RISK_CYTO, data = Final_cox_146)

                        n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
RISK_CYTO=Good         31     10     NA    46.5      NA
RISK_CYTO=Intermediate 79     56   18.5    11.3    28.4
RISK_CYTO=N.D.          3      2    5.7     1.3      NA
RISK_CYTO=Poor         33     24    7.7     4.2    52.7
```

and when I check the summary of the object i see this output

```
summary(TMB_NONSYNONYMOUS)
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(OS_MONTHS, Status) ~ RISK_CYTO, data = Final_cox_146)

                RISK_CYTO=Good 
 time n.risk n.event survival std.err lower 95% CI upper 95% CI
  0.2     31       1    0.968  0.0317        0.908        1.000
  0.7     30       1    0.935  0.0441        0.853        1.000
  1.0     29       1    0.903  0.0531        0.805        1.000
  4.5     28       1    0.871  0.0602        0.761        0.997
  8.0     27       1    0.839  0.0661        0.719        0.979
 19.2     26       1    0.806  0.0710        0.679        0.958
 26.3     25       1    0.774  0.0751        0.640        0.936
 30.6     20       1    0.735  0.0807        0.593        0.912
 45.8     13       1    0.679  0.0922        0.520        0.886
 46.5     12       1    0.622  0.1004        0.454        0.854

                RISK_CYTO=Intermediate 
 time n.risk n.event survival std.err lower 95% CI upper 95% CI
  0.1     79       1    0.987  0.0126        0.963        1.000
  0.3     78       1    0.975  0.0177        0.941        1.000
  0.5     77       1    0.962  0.0215        0.921        1.000
  0.8     76       2    0.937  0.0274        0.885        0.992
  2.3     74       1    0.924  0.0298        0.867        0.984
  2.4     73       1    0.911  0.0320        0.851        0.976
  3.1     72       1    0.899  0.0339        0.835        0.968
  4.6     71       1    0.886  0.0357        0.819        0.959
  5.2     70       1    0.873  0.0374        0.803        0.950
  5.3     69       1    0.861  0.0390        0.788        0.941
  5.5     68       1    0.848  0.0404        0.773        0.931
  5.7     67       1    0.835  0.0417        0.758        0.921
  6.3     66       2    0.810  0.0441        0.728        0.901
  6.6     64       1    0.797  0.0452        0.714        0.891
  7.1     62       1    0.785  0.0463        0.699        0.881
  7.4     61       1    0.772  0.0473        0.684        0.870
  7.5     60       2    0.746  0.0491        0.656        0.849
  7.7     58       1    0.733  0.0499        0.642        0.838
  7.9     57       1    0.720  0.0506        0.628        0.827
  8.1     56       2    0.695  0.0520        0.600        0.804
  8.2     54       1    0.682  0.0526        0.586        0.793
  8.4     53       1    0.669  0.0532        0.572        0.782
  9.3     52       1    0.656  0.0537        0.559        0.770
 10.2     51       2    0.630  0.0546        0.532        0.747
 10.7     49       1    0.617  0.0549        0.519        0.735
 11.2     48       1    0.605  0.0553        0.505        0.723
 11.3     47       1    0.592  0.0556        0.492        0.711
 11.5     46       1    0.579  0.0558        0.479        0.699
 15.4     44       1    0.566  0.0561        0.466        0.687
 16.3     43       1    0.552  0.0563        0.452        0.675
 16.4     42       1    0.539  0.0565        0.439        0.662
 17.0     41       1    0.526  0.0566        0.426        0.650
 18.1     40       1    0.513  0.0567        0.413        0.637
 18.5     39       1    0.500  0.0568        0.400        0.624
 19.0     38       1    0.487  0.0568        0.387        0.612
 20.5     37       2    0.460  0.0567        0.362        0.586
 22.3     35       1    0.447  0.0566        0.349        0.573
 24.1     33       1    0.434  0.0564        0.336        0.560
 24.8     32       1    0.420  0.0563        0.323        0.546
 25.8     31       1    0.407  0.0561        0.310        0.533
 27.0     28       1    0.392  0.0559        0.296        0.519
 27.4     26       1    0.377  0.0558        0.282        0.504
 28.4     25       1    0.362  0.0555        0.268        0.489
 30.0     24       1    0.347  0.0552        0.254        0.474
 32.3     23       1    0.332  0.0549        0.240        0.459
 34.0     21       1    0.316  0.0545        0.225        0.443
 46.8     14       1    0.293  0.0551        0.203        0.424
 53.9     11       1    0.267  0.0561        0.177        0.403
 55.4     10       1    0.240  0.0565        0.151        0.381
 56.3      9       1    0.213  0.0562        0.127        0.357

                RISK_CYTO=N.D. 
 time n.risk n.event survival std.err lower 95% CI upper 95% CI
  1.3      3       1    0.667   0.272       0.2995            1
  5.7      2       1    0.333   0.272       0.0673            1

                RISK_CYTO=Poor 
 time n.risk n.event survival std.err lower 95% CI upper 95% CI
  0.3     33       1    0.970  0.0298        0.913        1.000
  0.5     32       1    0.939  0.0415        0.861        1.000
  0.6     31       1    0.909  0.0500        0.816        1.000
  1.2     30       1    0.879  0.0568        0.774        0.998
  1.3     29       1    0.848  0.0624        0.735        0.980
  1.4     28       1    0.818  0.0671        0.697        0.961
  1.6     27       1    0.788  0.0712        0.660        0.940
  1.9     26       1    0.758  0.0746        0.625        0.919
  2.4     25       1    0.727  0.0775        0.590        0.896
  3.9     24       1    0.697  0.0800        0.557        0.873
  4.0     23       1    0.667  0.0821        0.524        0.849
  4.2     22       1    0.636  0.0837        0.492        0.824
  4.6     21       1    0.606  0.0851        0.460        0.798
  5.6     20       1    0.576  0.0860        0.430        0.772
  6.6     19       1    0.545  0.0867        0.399        0.745
  7.0     18       1    0.515  0.0870        0.370        0.717
  7.7     17       1    0.485  0.0870        0.341        0.689
  9.3     16       1    0.455  0.0867        0.313        0.661
 11.0     14       1    0.422  0.0864        0.283        0.630
 11.8     13       1    0.390  0.0856        0.253        0.599
 12.2     12       1    0.357  0.0844        0.225        0.568
 21.5     11       1    0.325  0.0827        0.197        0.535
 26.3     10       1    0.292  0.0806        0.170        0.502
 52.7      5       1    0.234  0.0830        0.117        0.469
```

**QUESTIONS**

1. **From the graph which it seems to me the intermediate patients have longer survival as compared to Good and Poor, is that correct interpretation?**
2. **Why there is NA in the median survival for Good Cytogenetic case as seen in the first data frame?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines on a KM plot show what percentage of each group of patients survived to each time point. Lines near the top show "better" survival, with a higher proportion of patients surviving for longer, while lines that drop steeply to the bottom show worse survival, with only a small percentage of the group surviving even a short while.

In this plot, we see the red "Good" line has the best survival, with the highest proportion of patients surviving the longest. The blue "Intermediate" line is the next best, followed by the (fairly similar) green "ND" and grey "Poor" groups.

The left-right *length* of the lines just shows the follow-up time for different groups, but that doesn't indicate better survival. The blue line happens to be the longest meaning there was at least one person who was followed-up and survived longer than anyone else we have data for, but that doesn't mean the blue group is better overall than others. How far the line stretches to the right depends only on the survival time of the *last* person left in that group at the end, and doesn't really represent aggregate group behavior Many people in the red line simply got censored, meaning they were still alive when the trial ended - they may well have survived as long or even longer than that person in the blue line had the trial continued.

As for median survival, people often misinterpret this as the "median of survival times", which is incorrect. The "median of survival times" always exists, but is actually a fairly useless number, as it does not respect if patients got censored or had an event at their follow-up time. The median survival is the *time at which 50% of the population survives*. Here, the "Good" group *never* has its survival rate drop to 50%, so the median survival time is NA.

Comment: "The blue line happens to be the longest meaning there was at least one person who was followed-up and survived longer than anyone else we have data for, but that doesn't mean the blue group is better overall than others" this is what i was not able to get it

Comment: @PesKchan Suppose this is a clinical trial, and someone in the blue group begins on the very first day of the trial. Not all patients are recruited at the same time, so maybe some folks in the red group don't start on the trial for another year. If the trial ends 2 years later, we see the blue group may have 3 years of survival data but the red group only 2 years, even if both groups have the same outcome overall.

Comment: @PesKchan Basically, the line ends when the *last* person has an event or is censored - the length of the line really just tells you the follow-up time of that single individual. You could add 1 person to each group with 20 years of follow-up data and see the lines stretch very far to the right, but the addition of that one person would not  meaningfully change the survival behavior of the group *as a whole*.

Comment: @PesKchan The graph shows that about 20% of the blue group survived to nearly 120 months, and that about 70% of the red group survived to about 100 months (after that we don't have data for the red group). You can compare at time points for which there is both red and blue data - at any time point you choose (under 100 months), there is a higher proportion of red group survivors than blue group survivors.

Comment: thank you for the clear explanation